# Two sets of large numbers - fraction of their sums

Tags: java, integer

I have two sets of large numbers. The task is simple - add all the ints from set A and divide it by the sum of all ints in set B.

The problem is the numbers are very large, their sum might easily exceed the maximum of int or even long and there are quite a few of them in both sets. What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which can support very long numbers.